# Twisted Telnet Server: how to avoid nested CRLF

Tags: python, twisted, telnet

I'm implementing a Telnet Server where I have two Telnet implementations: Pre-authentication and Post-authentication.

The core issue is that the server sends `\r\r\n` instead of `\r\n`. By step debugging I found out that it is due to the `ProtocolTransportMixin` that is there twice in the class heriarchy. I believe that it is due to pre-auth and post-auth transports that are somehow interlinked (one being the base transport of the other).

Is there a way I can cancel the effect of one of the mixins?

My Telnet server factory instantiates with

```
lambda: TelnetTransport(MyOwnTelnetAuthTransport, ...)
```

`MyOwnTelnetAuthTransport` is a subclass of `AuthenticatingTelnetProtocol`.

Post-authentication, I connect it through a realm with my own subclass of `TelnetBootstrapProtocol`.

Since both `TelnetTransport` and `TelnetBootstrapProtocol` have the `ProtocolTransportMixin` which substitutes `\n` for `\r\n` in its `write()` method I end up with `\r\r\n`...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with kind of a hack. Still looking for better solutions.

Subclassing `TelnetTransport` with `MyTelnet` with the following implementation:

```
class MyTelnet(TelnetTransport):
    """Sole purpose is to override write() and fix a CRLF nesting bug"""

    # Because of the presence of two ProtocolTransportMixin in the protocol
    # stack once authenticated, I need to override write() and remove a \r
    # otherwise we end up with \r\r\n on the wire.
    def write(self, bytes):
        self.transport.write(bytes.replace('\r\n', '\n'))
```

Then adjusting my factory to spawn this class instead of `TelnetTransport` fixed it.

Comment: Although this will appear to work 99.9̅% of the time, technically speaking it is incorrect, because the caller *might* call `write("\r")` and then `write("\n")`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're actually authenticating users, don't use telnet.  Use SSH.  Twisted provides [`conch`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.conch.html), which already implements the protocol.

Second, when you ask a question like this, please always provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). I don't know what your actual problem is unless I can run your code, and I'm not going to reconstruct your code based on a loose description.

Finally though, it sounds like you've just discovered a bug in Twisted here, and you should file it.  `TelnetTransport` should not be doubling up on `CR`s, so if that is indeed what's happening, it shouldn't be a hacky workaround in your code but a fix upstream.

P.S.: `MyOwnTelnetAuthTransport` is not a transport, it's a `TelnetProtocol`, so the naming is a bit confusing.  If you have put a `Transport` class in its hierarchy, perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: It is for a honeypot to catch malware on the Internet. I'm explicitly implementing a Telnet authentication to a twisted-based SSH honeypot so it can have more coverage.

Comment: I would have liked to provide an SSCCE but it involves a Portal, an Avatar, Telnet protocols, factories, Authentication classes and then hooking into Terminal (History.Recvline or something)... I might come back and provide it but it is a non-trivial amount of work. I want to deliver my project so I can move on to my job: malware analysis. It is a hack but it works so the incentive for SSCCE lowered quite a bit. This PR can give you an idea of what I've done: https://github.com/micheloosterhof/cowrie/compare/master...GoSecure:telnet-wip?expand=1

Comment: Addressing the PS: I find that the framework isn't clear about the difference between a transport and a protocol. I've read a lot of the twisted docs and source code in the past weeks as I was implementing this and it still isn't clear to me in the Telnet context. I might have mixed the two. I'll definitely rename the class to express the right intent. Thanks!

Comment: I realize you want to get back to your job. But I would also like to get back to *my* job, and the more work you do up front the easier it is to answer the question.